# Outlook web addin in ribbon

Tags: c#, office365, outlook-addin, visual-studio-2022, outlook-web-addins

I have a developed a web addin, and as per my understanding the DesktopFactor should add ribbon in Outlook desktop, but it is not showing any ribbon rather it displayed the addin when I open any email and click on "..." in the email

So I decided to give demo manifest a shot, referring manifest from
https://github.com/OfficeDev/script-lab/blob/master/manifests/script-lab-react-prod.outlook.xml
but the same is happening,
[image]

the addin is not visible in ribbon, instead it is opened from email ..., as per msdn the outlook desktop should show the menu in ribbon, can anyone highlight where this is going wrong...

Comment: Thanks for reaching out. This is an expected behavior. Addins might end up inside the overflow menu of the ribbon which opens after clicking ....

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT can we have a addin activated with email selection/ composing email/ appointment? Like our earlier VSTO addin allows us to create menu in the main Menu bar (Home/ View/ bar)  or there is no way we can add menu or ribbon in Outllok

Comment: Outlook 365 on desktop adds ribbon in toolbar, but if we click on "New Outllook" switch , the addin is no more visible on ribbon rather added in flyout of email. This behaviour is ok on web outlook but the same happening with installed version when we click the "New Outlook" switch

Comment: Flyout is present in both New Outlook and OWA. For easy access of Addin, you can add them in the same line where Flyout is present by using
Settings -> Customize Actions.